# String was not recognized as a valid datetime - Datetime conversion issue

Tags: c#, datetime

I am having a date like `"19/01/2018 15:30"` as string.
I need to convert this to a DateTime object.

I am getting error:

> String was not recognized as a valid datetime

This is my code:

```
DateTime drawDatetime = DateTime.ParseExact("19/01/2018 15:30"
    , "dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss", null);
```

Comment: You format string contains seconds but the date doesn't.

Comment: Why don't we still have a canonical _"The format you specify for DateTime.ParseExact() must match the format of the date string you pass it"_?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You format string contains seconds but the date doesn't. Try this instead:

```
DateTime drawDatetime = DateTime.ParseExact(
    "19/01/2018 15:30", 
    "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm", null);
```

Comment: sorry, it wasn't working. I fixed it in some other way

Comment: @spidie_sridhar Oh yes, the hour format string needs to be in uppercase as it's a 24 hour clock. So the update will work now.

Comment: `ParseExact("19/01/2018 15:30", "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);`

It helped me, buddy :)